# Постановка запятых

Tags: пунктуация

Почему во фразе *квартира () где я живу* запятая ставится, а во фразе *родственники по материнской линии () наконец приехали* - нет? Хотя в первом случае никакой паузы при произношении нет, а во втором - есть.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Постановка знаков препинания определяется структурой предложения. Очень часто, но далеко не всегда знаку знаку препинания на письме соответствует пауза в устной речи (и наоборот). Ваша первая фраза представляет собой сложноподчиненное предложения с придаточным определительным. Придаточное предложение отделяется от главного запятой. Слово наконец во втором предложении не является вводным (проверяем заменой на наконец-то). В этой фразе присутствует обычная  пауза между подлежащим и сказуемым. Но запятая между подлежащим и сказуемым не ставится.

Comment: Если знаки препинания означают не паузы в речи, то что они обозначают?

Comment: >Если знаки препинания означают не паузы в речи, то что они обозначают?    
  
В первую очередь - синтаксис, т.е. структуру предложения. Интонацию и паузы - в последнюю. И как правило такие знаки - авторские.

Answer (score 0):

Потому что постановка знаков препинания регулируется не паузами при произношении, а правилами пунктуации.