# Нужно ли стать запятую после подлежащего "Несколько месяцев назад"?

Tags: пунктуация

**Нужно ли стать запятую после подлежащего "Несколько месяцев назад"?**

**Примеры предложений:**

- Несколько месяцев назад, один из самых любимых телесериалов "Час Х", появился в прокате.
- Меньше месяца назад, 16 апреля, по всему миру прошел Тотальный диктант по русскому языку — самая масштабная на планете акция по проверке грамотности.

**Анализ:**

- предложения имеют разложимое сочетание без цельного состава по смыслу выражения, которое допускает запятую;
- это "один из самых любимых телесериалов "Час Х", появился в прокате" придаточное предложение, типа "обстоятельственные", а после придаточных предложений нужно ставить запятую;
- даже когда мы произносим это предложение, мы проглатываем воздух, делаем паузу.
  Несколько месяцев назад (проглотили воздух)(Что произошло несколько месяцев назад?), один из моих очень весёлых
  студентов по имени Кикий, пришел ко мне. А так как, запятые существуют для того, чтобы передать точную конструкцию предложения, то этот аргумент заслуживает внимания к рассмотрению данного вопроса.
- Портал "meduza.io", попросил главного редактора портала «Грамота.ру» Владимира Пахомова напомнить, как правильно ставить знаки препинания. Владимир Пахомов написав статью поставил запятую в схожей конструкции предложения, вот:

> Меньше месяца назад, 16 апреля, по всему миру прошел Тотальный диктант
>   по русскому языку — самая масштабная на планете акция по проверке
>   грамотности. Накануне диктанта «Медуза» рассказывала о базовых
>   орфографических правилах. После этого сразу несколько читателей
>   написали в редакцию, что нужны карточки и о пунктуации. Мы попросили
>   главного редактора портала «Грамота.ру» Владимира Пахомова напомнить,
>   как правильно ставить знаки препинания.

https://meduza.io/cards/kak-pravilno-stavit-znaki-prepinaniya

Comment: «Владимир Пахомов написав статью поставил запятую в схожей конструкции предложения, вот:
Меньше месяца назад...» Нужно ли ставить здесь запятые, и что такое «вот» перед цитатой?

Comment: @shampar это не цитата.

Comment: Назовите как хотите, но «вот» перед абзацем стоит.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вы ошибаетесь, слова "несколько месяцев назад" не являются подлежащим.

О постановке запятых. Возможно, Вас ввело в заблуждение второе предложение: *"Меньше месяца назад, 16 апреля, по всему миру прошел Тотальный диктант по русскому языку...*" В нем запятыми выделено уточняющее обстоятельство. Если его убрать, получим: "*Меньше месяца назад по всему миру прошел Тотальный диктант по русскому языку...*"

> Постановка знаков препинания определяется структурой предложения. Очень часто, но далеко не всегда знаку знаку препинания на письме соответствует пауза в устной речи (и наоборот).  (@Ларf) См. 
>   [Постановка запятых](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/21696/%d0%9f%d0%be%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%ba%d0%b0-%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%bf%d1%8f%d1%82%d1%8b%d1%85/21698#21698).

Comment: Спасибо за полезный ответ! Завтра вам скажут что точки в русском языке отменили, и вы будете говорить, точки уже не нужны. Я же считаю, что хорошо запоминать и правильно интерпретировать информацию, является важной частью обучающего процесса,  но помимо этого, нужно быть и самим исследователем, чтобы находить неправильные, ложные понятия и заменять их на истинные. Запятые должны быть разделителем предложения, использующиеся с целью наиболее точной передачи конструкции предложения, именно такой конструкции, какую передаёт сам оппонент, и никаких жестких рамок быть не должно по отношению к запят

Comment: @ЮрийСветлов *Завтра вам скажут что точки в русском языке отменили* - а в котором часу и по какой программе?

Comment: @ЮрийСветлов *нужно быть и самим исследователем, чтобы находить неправильные, ложные понятия и заменять их на истинные* - и сжигать всех, кто с истинными не согласен?

Answer (score 2):

Не нужно, и это не подлежащее - кроме фантастического случая, когда "Несколько месяцев назад" (в кавычках) оказывается названием сериала, а "Час Х" трактуется как наименование дружного клуба любителей сериалов.

Answer (score 2):

1) Русская пунктуация основана на **интонационно-грамматическом принципе**, поэтому не каждая пауза (глотание воздуха) обозначается запятой. Знаки препинания выявляют грамматику и структуру предложения в тех случаях, когда в этом есть необходимость.

А когда такой необходимости  нет? Вот именно тогда, когда пауза является произносительной и через несколько слов, объединенных в смысловые отрезки, мы "глотаем воздух". В этих местах обычно и ставятся ошибочные запятые.

2) Хорошо известно, что в простом неосложненном предложении **запятых нет**, а вот **паузы там есть**. А если предложение распространенное, то и несколько пауз может быть.

3) **Несколько месяцев назад / один из самых любимых телесериалов "Час Х"// появился в прокате.** Простое предложение, обстоятельственный детерминант в его начале не обособляется.  Но при желании его можно заменить придаточным предложением, например: **И только когда прошло несколько месяцев, один из самых любимых телесериалов "Час Х" появился в прокате.**  Тогда запятая обозначает структуру сложного предложения.

4) **Меньше месяца назад, 16 апреля, по всему миру прошел Тотальный диктант по русскому языку — самая масштабная на планете акция по проверке грамотности**.

Уточняющее обстоятельство (когда именно) обособляется запятыми. Распространенное приложение в конце предложения обособляется тире. Это тема обособления второстепенных членов, где подробно объясняется когда и почему они обособляются.

Answer (score 1):

> *Нужно ли стать запятую после подлежащего "Несколько месяцев назад"?*

Вопрос бессмысленный,  "Несколько месяцев назад" не может являться подлежащим (если только это не какая-то очень хитроумная фраза), "назад" этому мешает. В обычных примерах эту конструкцию следует трактовать скорее всего как временной обстоятельственный оборот, который по правилам обособляется опционально.

Что же касается текста от "Медузы", то запятая там по причине уточняющего "16 апреля".